# Can't get @fontface CSS to work in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'm pretty sure this is what I've always done in the past, but I can't get it to work this time. The folder AFONTNAME is in the fonts folder within the active theme folder:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "A Font Name";
  src: url("/fonts/AFONTNAME/AFONTNAME.ttf") format("ttf"),
       url("/fonts/AFONTNAME/AFONTNAME.woff") format("woff"),
       url("/fonts/AFONTNAME/AFONTNAME.svg") format("svg");

}

.specialfont { font-family: "A Font Name" }
```

Have tried using the full path to the fonts folder, with and without font-weights and with and without the SVG font. No matter what I do, targeted content only displays in Times Roman. Since this is not the theme's default font it leads me to believe the path is correct, but something else in incorrect.

Comment: Realized the version I posted is missing semicolon after "A Font Name". Note that it's correct in my CSS.

Comment: Have you checked in the inspector if the font is loaded?

Comment: Hi Botond. No. What am I looking for in the inspector?

Comment: in Firefox, or Chrome go to network, do a refresh, and see if your font is in the list

Comment: Where are you putting that CSS?

Comment: Hi A Haworth: Putting the CSS in ADMIN > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS

Comment: Hi Botond: Wow. It's actually working (font loading properly)in Chrome (87.0.4280.88), but not in Firefox (83.0) or Safari (Mac 14.0). I always work in Safari. Any ideas on why?